# Cannot run IntelliJ - NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, azul-zulu

I am unable to start IntelliJ with my fresh installed OpenSUSE 13.2

Here's the logs:

```
xybrek@opensuse:~/idea-IC-139.659.2/bin> ./idea.sh 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.<clinit>(RepaintManager.java:226)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4798)
    at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3303)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setEditable(JTextComponent.java:1758)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:309)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:199)
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(JTextPane.java:90)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:221)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:208)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:81)
xybrek@opensuse:~/idea-IC-139.659.2/bin> java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.4.0.1-linux64) (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.4.0.1-linux64) (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue on OpenSUSE machine with not installed fonts. You may want to try to fix that by installing x11 fonts:

```
zypper install xorg-x11-fonts xorg-x11-fonts-core
```

Oracle JDK worked because they have proprietary fonts included in the bundle and fontconfig.properties for them.

Comment: Note that now you can also download Zulu Compatibility Pack to address that: http://zulu.org/developer-resources/commercial-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems Zulu JDK do not have this class (I am not sure) however I have fixed this issue by using the Oracle JDK (tar.gz package will do). Unzip it into a folder path then set the `IDEA_JDK=/path/to/jdk` in `~/.bashrc` for Linux.

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear that Zulu didn't work for you "out of the box". Azul tests Zulu on a variety of linux platforms and the issue that yo have described is not known. I does look though as if the Idea is being launched with a `java.awt.headless=true` parameter being set. That could creep in via the `JAVA_OPTIONS` env variable for example.
If you still want to pursue the Zulu as the JRE engine for your Idea runs - we would be happy to assist. We would need to clarify a few system parameters though.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use Zulu to be used for Development in both apps we make and the tools we use