# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment in my gradle build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am using gradle to build Android app and running into below error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Assist:mergeAnimationReleaseResources'.

  > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
  >   -- Would someone please point me the reason and how to resolve ? Thanks for your comments a lot :)

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084674/cannot-run-intellij-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-sun-awt-x i think it solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your comments a lot. Since I am working on a workstation, I cannot install or change anything in it. What I can do is to modify build.gradle and Android.mk